# How to set QoS on Tenda router to reduce ping

Tags: networking, router, ping, qos

I have an Tenda router and I would like to set QoS so that i would would have low ping no matter what other people living with me do. There are 7 people living in out house, and our connection speed is 600 kB/s.

I have tried to set it up myselft and google around, with so success. I have basic understanding how TCP/IP protocol works, but I don't know how to set QoS.

One of the more ideal solution would be to reserve let's say 10% of the connection bandwith exclusivly to me, and the rest 90% to everybody (including me). I don't mind if I get high ping when I'm downloading torrent, I only don't want other people affecting my ping.

Here are screens from the QoS settings pages:

Main page:
[image: Main page]

QoS Queue:
[image: QoS Queue]

QoS Queue, after clicking Add:
[image: QoS Queue, after clicking Add]

QoS Classification:
[image: QoS Classification]

QoS Classification, after clicking Add:
[image: QoS Classification, after clicking Add]

And yes, i know i can affect only outgoing data, but that's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Various applications including ping and other ICMP based tools where invented to measure the health of IP network virtually spending no extra costs. And it was highly recommended not to play with ICMP features unless otherwise necessary to overall operations. Modifying ICMP traffic actual value with QoS may introduce more problems than it may overcome.

From my experience over ISP environment QoS of ICMP traffic mostly attractive to people who actually try hiding their bandwidth misuse. Keep in mind that QoS might give you lower latency on network monitoring but ultimately overall performance of your network will doomed.

After knowing all those negative outcome, if you still prefer to go for your plan, you can simply use bandwidth shaping rules. First give some bandwidth for any ICMP packets arrived at router interface and place some strict limits on rest of applications. It is also recommended that 80% capacity would be treated as full utilization. So place some amount of bandwidth for ICMP traffic and 80% of remaining bandwidth is maximum amount for other purposes and usages. It is also need to consider that every QoS rules costs CPU usage. So too many rules ultimately lead to total failure of performance if resources limitations are not taken in consideration...

Answer (score 0):

High latency (high ping times and other round-trip times/RTTs) is usually caused by [Bufferbloat](https://bufferbloat.net/) and is best solved by loading OpenWrt and enabling Cake (or FQ-CoDel).

To see if you have bufferbloat, run http://dslreport.com/speedtest and see what bufferbloat grade you get.

It's better to solve bufferbloat than to try to work around it by prioritizing some traffic over others.